# UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

Tags: php, file-upload

i have a upload script that has been running for a few months without any problems.
But now i have the problem, that i have the error 6 on uploading (no tmp dir).
my $_FILES array looks like this:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "1.txt" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(6) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } }
```

So but when i run `phpinfo();` there is the system standard tmp dir at upload_tmp_dir.
Also when i run

```
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Tux');
echo $temp_file;
```

this is also no problem and i have a output and no error.

i have tried a blank upload form (w/o any other code) and also a realy small empty txt file.

has someone an idea whats going wrong?

thank you

Skadie

Comment: It can be worth checking it the value for `upload_tmp_dir` you see in `phpinfo()` is the one seen by the upload script itself. You can check that with [ini_get()](https://php.net/ini_get).

Comment: ok i have checked.. but there is also in global and in local value the std tmp dir. what means access 4? ["upload_tmp_dir"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["global_value"]=>
    string(15) "C:\Windows\temp"
    ["local_value"]=>
    string(15) "C:\Windows\temp"
    ["access"]=>
    int(4)
  }

Comment: You aren't doing what I suggested, are you? I think you're repeating the same original check :-?

Comment: no i do it with ini_get_all();

Comment: By default, [ini_get_all()](https://php.net/ini_get_all) displays all the details about directives. `access` (access level) is a bitmap that says where a given directive can be set. The manual stops here () but [a user comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php#27840) suggests that `4` is for `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` ("Entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf"). That's [the default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads) (I'm not aware that's something the can be changed).

Comment: ok but where is my problem, that i have this error when i upload a file? ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') tolds me also string(15) "C:\Windows\temp".

Comment: Sorry, I was just answering your follow-up question. It all looks correct. Perhaps permissions have changed or your antivirus is getting on the way. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score -2):

```
$file_name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_tmp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: A little explanation of what the problem was and how your code solves that would be nice

Comment: $file_tmp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; is empty my $_Files array shows that:  array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "1.txt" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(6) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } }